# Could we use the foundation axiom to generate counterexamples to almost any substantial axiom?

Tags: set-theory, axiom

Here's the argument scheme I have in mind ("*F*" refers to a substantial/positive property/description; negative qualifiers like "inaccessible" do not sustain this scheme correctly):

1. ∃κ∀<sub>any</sub>λ(*F*λ →  (λ ∈ κ))
2. κ ∉ κ
3. ¬*F*κ

(Perhaps there is a way to define "any" in terms of "some" and "all" rather than having it be a different flavor of "all" alone. At any rate, perhaps it is not necessary to qualify the universal quantifier here in this way; perhaps speaking of "all" the lambdas doesn't conflict with asserting that kappa is the cut-off point for *F*.)

So one application I have in mind allows the axiom of infinity to be derived as a theorem (not clearly the same way as this is done in [Ackermann set theory](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/settheory-alternative/#AckeSetTheo) or even the [Quinean family of such theories](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/settheory-alternative/#ConsProbForNFKnowConsSubs)):

1. There is a set *X* of all finite sets: ∃*X*∀<sub>any</sub>*x*(finite(*x*) →  (*x* ∈ *X*))
2. If ultrafinitism were true, *X* would itself have to be finite, and then an element of itself.
3. But instead *X* ∉ *X*
4. ¬finite(*X*)

Or we can construct arbitrary counterexamples to choice, powerset, and singleton axioms:

5. There is a set *X* whose elements *x* are those sets with singletons above them.
6. So *X* does not itself have a singleton above it (it is "too large" to fit into a singleton).
7. Or there is a set *X* of all *x* that have powersets above them.
8. So *X* is powerless.
9. Or *X* is the set of all *x* that can be well-ordered by the axiom of choice.
10. So *X*, even if well-orderable, is not to be so by the axiom of choice.

And we can go on and on like this; perhaps Reinhardts on the strictly class-embedding (vs. rank-embedding) level might be construed as counterexamples to the whole theme of embeddings, say (Berkeleys look kind of like this too, though, or even more precisely (they also have a flavor of "inaccessibility" to their introduction, except the inaccessibility is embedding-operational instead of powerset/cofinality-operational)).

I imagine that this argument scheme faces a naive comprehension danger, though:

1. There is an *X* whose elements are all well-founded *x*.<sup>**!!!**</sup>
2. Therefore *X* itself is not well-founded.
3. There are two species of parafounded elementhood, circular and infinitely-descending.
4. If *X* were circularly parafounded, it would be an element of itself, but then it would have to be well-founded, but then Russell's paradox looms.
5. So if there is a set of all well-founded sets, this set must be an infinite descending elementhood chain.

Is the danger of naive comprehension what prevents set theorists from using the foundation axiom to form generic counterexamples to various axioms? Or does the argument scheme given at the outset, here, work just fine in that the universal quantification involved does *not* lead to naive comprehension?

---

***Postscript (edit).*** It is possible to use the embedding operation that generates Reinhardt cardinals, but not to the extent that generates the choice-violators, if one abridges [the replacement scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wholeness_axiom). However, my intuition is telling me that on account of esoteric ["limitation of size"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_limitation_of_size) reasons, the replacement scheme, despite being substantive/positive, is an axiom scheme that does *not* have justifiable exceptions. "The well-founded set of all sets obeying replacement axioms" would not obey replacement axioms, granted; yet I would prefer to tailor my use of comprehension schematics to block the formation of such a set.

<sup>**!!!**</sup>What about "the well-founded set of all *other* well-founded sets"? That seems possible, maybe. Nevertheless, if there is a set of all well-founded sets whatsoever, this set must not itself be well-founded.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "ultrafinitism", but ZF entails that there are an infinite number of finite sets. See Russel's construction of the natural numbers for an example.

Comment: @DavidGudeman, ultrafinitism is, roughly, the belief in a largest finite number or set. It is more aggressive than what is usually called just finitism, then. However, it seems easy to turn ultrafinitism, as a kind of set theory, into a set theory will an unwell-founded set, which might conflict with the foundationalist themes of intuitionism (and ultrafinitism as a case of intuitionism, then).

Comment: So your real point is that the foundation theory is inconsistent with ultrafinitism? If so, you should probably mention that in the question title.

Comment: @DavidGudeman, no it's not really an open question, for me, that ultrafinitism is inconsistent with foundationalism, here. Instead, that inconsistency is mentioned as an example of a broader argument scheme that seems to allow for converting most set-theoretic axioms into [dependent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_dependent_choice) versions of themselves, i.e. versions that "run out" when we go up the hierarchy far enough.

Answer (score 0):

The only information about this possibility that I found in the extant literature was a mention in ["Alternative Axiomatic Set Theories"](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/settheory-alternative/#MultViewSetTheo) of Hamkin's *well-foundedness mirage*: "Every universe *V* is ill-founded from the perspective of another, better universe":

> Hamkins says that this may be the most provocative of all his axioms. He states that he intends this to imply that even our notion of natural numbers is defective in any universe: the collection of natural numbers as defined in any universe is seen to contain nonstandard elements from the standpoint of a further universe.

I'll look for Hamkins' specific, relevant article for more information; I think I've read it before, as I have a fuzzy memory of something like the phrase "uncountable and well-founded from the perspective of *V* but countable and ill-founded from the perspective of *W*," for some *W* > some *V*. I don't know if "countable" there is meant as, "*V* is equivalent to the zeroth aleph," or rather if the *cofinality* of *V* is countable, regardless of how many alephs are in that *V* as a whole (Corazza's abridged-replacement world, for example, has countable cofinality but embedding-theoretically many cardinals, after all). Or perhaps there are multiple articles in play; if it's not the same as the above-mentioned one, I recall another essay by Hamkins about nonlinear/ill-founded relations between axioms/schemes, his broad counterargument to the picture, familiar from [Peter Koellner's assessment of the situation](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/independence-large-cardinals/#IntHie), according to which the "natural" large-cardinal axioms all fit neatly into a well-founded and well-ordered system.

Comment: But you wanna generate counterexamples to other substantive axioms, say axiom of spec,  implicitly in the same universe, then why the well-foundedness mirage from the POV of another better universe gonna help you?...

Comment: @DoubleKnot, although we'd usually talk of a proper class of WF-sets rather than an ~WF-set of WF-sets, Hamkins has a conversion protocol where *V* becomes a rank for some *W*, so I suppose that the inability to form a WF-set of all WF-sets is similar. I read through Asaf Karagila's answer to a question about the mirage over on the MathSE/Overflow which reminded me of something I accidentally derived on my end, so I'll look into it some more, maybe I'm just reinventing a wheel, so to say. At any rate, if I think I have a good line of reasoning, I'll try it out at the Overflow.

Comment: @DoubleKnot also, the universe(s) generated by the well-foundedness filter (for singleton-minus, powerlessness, etc.) are not necessarily closed in the same sense as a "classical" universe. The WF-set of all knowable WF-sets, , is not itself knowable, so  represents an inherently vague boundary in the cardinal ascent. At one time in history, we knew little to nothing of measurables and Mahlos; later, we had to learn of extendibles and Reinhardts and Berkeleys; presumably we will always have more to learn?

Comment: @DoubleKnot also, then, not that absolute infinity itself is growing; conceptually, it is the maximum of the concept of size, so growth has to be either false or metaphorical of it. Or, at worst, *V* is incommensurable with the other cardinals (note that the WF-set of all sets commensurable with each other will not be commensurable with its elements). However, it is our own limitations with respect to absolute concepts that then are in play as limitations as to what is known/knowable of *V* at any given time, although to be sure ~WF knowledge sets complicate matters gravely.

Comment: For most of your above conclusions/speculations, Munchausen trilemma and the problem of criterion in epistemology already hinted in our physical world ~WF knowledge sets is a very likely reality with about 1/2 to 2/3 prior probability. Also hinted long ago in [The Wonderful Dharma Lotus Flower Sutra](http://www.cttbusa.org/lotus/lotus2.asp.html): *Truly, suppose the ten directions, Were filled with those like Shariputra, And that the remaining disciples filled All the lands in the ten directions, And that together they spent their thoughts to measure it, They also could not know it...*